# What to do with classes within classes?

Tags: java, class

I am currently creating a events recorder GUI program. Yet I am encountering a very difficult problem.

How should I store objects within an object within an object within an object?

For example,
I have an event.
This event has 4 category.
In the first category (Category A), there are 30 exhibition shows.
Within each show, there are 20 - 30 representatives. (Let's say 30 reps for the first show).
...

How can I store all these information in an arraylist? OR is there any other better idea?

Should I also apply Polymorphism to this one too?
Event --> Category A (first one out of the four) --> First Show out of 30 --> 1 rep out of 30 reps --> ... etc.

Thanks.

My confusion is that I would like to treat every single of these as an object. For example, category is an object. The show is an object. The reps is an object. My question is how can I store an object within an object within an object and so on? Thanks.

Comment: Put a variable in the class, and repeat till all your objects inside objects dreams come true!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this

Test.java

```
import java.util.List;


public class Test {
    public List<Category> category;
}
```

import java.util.List;

Category.java

```
public class Category {

    public List<Exhibition> exhibitionShow;
    public void setExhibitionShow(List<Exhibition> exhibitionShow) {
        this.exhibitionShow = exhibitionShow;
    }
    public List<Exhibition> getExhibitionShow() {
        return exhibitionShow;
    }

}
```

Exhibition.java

import java.util.List;

```
public class Exhibition {
    public List<Representative> representative;

    public void setRepresentative(List<Representative> representative) {
        this.representative = representative;
    }

    public List<Representative> getRepresentative() {
        return representative;
    }
}
```

Representative .java

```
public class Representative {   
//add method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your confusion, you need to do something like this

```
class Event{
    Category[] categories;
}

class Category{
    ArrayList<Show> shows;
}

class Show{
    ArrayList<Representative> reps;
}

//.. and so on.
```

Comment: My confusion is that I would like to treat every single of these as an object.

For example, category is an object. The show is an object. The reps is an object.

My question is how can I store an object within an object within an object and so on? Thanks.

Comment: That makes no sense.... When you take a fully initialized Event object and if it's data is properly populated, the Event instance has all the other instances inside it.

Comment: @user1799252 this is exactly what you want. If it is still confusing, perhaps a good OOP book is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the idea. My idea is create one public method.